# Make child elements active

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code that can be used to filter cars by country of manufacture. The code is structured like this: I put the name of the country with a checkbox in the title ExpansionTile; I put the name of the cars with checkboxes in the children ExpansionTile.
Those. the user can tick either only the country, or only the names (name) of the car, or all together.

But I would like to implement the idea that if the user puts a checkmark next to the name of the country, then the checkboxes in front of the cars would be automatically checked. Similar to the functionality from this example https://medium.com/@nishsvn.dev/flutter-parent-and-child-checkboxes-part-2-98ce62156004

```
    class _FilterDialogUserState extends State<FilterDialogUser> {
  Map<String, List<String>?> filters = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    filters = widget.initialState;
  }

  void _handleCheckFilter(bool checked, String key, String value) {
    final currentFilters = filters[key] ?? [];
    if (checked) {
      currentFilters.add(value);
    } else {
      currentFilters.remove(value);
    }
    setState(() {
      filters[key] = currentFilters;
    });
  }

  final countries = [
    Country(
      name: 'Germany',
      cars: [
        Car(name: 'Audi'),
        Car(name: 'BMW'),
        Car(name: 'Volkswagen'),
      ],
    ),
    Country(
      name: 'Sweden',
      cars: [
        Car(name: 'Koenigsegg'),
        Car(name: 'Polestar'),
        Car(name: 'Volvo'),
      ],
    ),
    Country(
      name: 'Russian',
      cars: [
        Car(name: 'GAZ'),
        Car(name: 'Lada'),
        Car(name: 'ZAZ'),
      ],
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
        title: const Text('Filters',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: 'SuisseIntl',
            )),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                for (Country country in countries)
                  ExpansionTile(
                      tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      title: CustomCheckboxTile(
                        value:
                        filters['country']?.contains(country.name) ?? false,
                        onChange: (check) =>
                            _handleCheckFilter(check, 'country', country.name),
                        label: country.name,
                      ),
                      initiallyExpanded: () {
                        for (final Car car in country.cars) {
                          if (filters['cars']?.contains(car.name) ?? false) {
                            return true;
                          }
                        }
                        return false;
                      }(),
                      children: [
                        for (Car car in country.cars)
                          CustomCheckboxTile(
                            value: filters['cars']?.contains(car.name) ?? false,
                            onChange: (check) =>
                                _handleCheckFilter(check, 'cars', car.name),
                            label: car.name,
                          )
                      ])
              ]),
       ........
```

If you need additional pieces of code to help solve the problem, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the relation between the **Checkbox of Country** and the **Checkbox of Car**. The most straightforward method to do in your code is updating the function of `_handleCheckFilter`. It needs some more additional information to update the filter.

I split it into 2 functions: `_handleCountryCheckFilter` and `_handleCarCheckFilter`:

**_handleCountryCheckFilter**

```
void _handleCountryCheckFilter(
    bool checked, String country, List<String> cars) {
  final countryFilters = filters['country'] ?? [];
  final carFilters = filters['cars'] ?? [];

  if (checked) {
    countryFilters.add(country);
    for (var car in cars) {
      if (!carFilters.contains(car)) {
        carFilters.add(car);
      }
    }
  } else {
    countryFilters.remove(country);
    for (var car in cars) {
      if (carFilters.contains(car)) {
        carFilters.remove(car);
      }
    }
  }
  setState(() {
    filters['country'] = countryFilters;
    filters['cars'] = carFilters;
  });
}
```

**_handleCarCheckFilter**

```
void _handleCarCheckFilter(
    bool checked, String car, String country, List<String> cars) {
  final countryFilters = filters['country'] ?? [];
  final carFilters = filters['cars'] ?? [];

  if (checked) {
    carFilters.add(car);

    var carIsFull = true;
    for (var car in cars) {
      if (!carFilters.contains(car)) {
        carIsFull = false;
      }
    }
    if (carIsFull && !countryFilters.contains(country)) {
      countryFilters.add(country);
    }
  } else {
    carFilters.remove(car);

    var carIsEmpty = true;
    for (var car in cars) {
      if (carFilters.contains(car)) {
        carIsEmpty = false;
      }
    }
    if (carIsEmpty) {
      countryFilters.remove(country);
    }
  }
  setState(() {
    filters['country'] = countryFilters;
    filters['cars'] = carFilters;
  });
}
```

Finally, you can change the **onChange** function of your **CustomCheckboxTile**:

```
// country checkbox
CustomCheckboxTile(
  value: filters['country']?.contains(country.name) ?? false,
  onChange: (check) => _handleCountryCheckFilter(check,country.name,country.cars.map((car) => car.name).toList()),
  label: country.name,
),

...
// country checkbox
CustomCheckboxTile(
  value: filters['cars']?.contains(car.name) ?? false,
  onChange: (check) => _handleCarCheckFilter(check,car.name,country.name,country.cars.map((car) => car.name).toList()),
  label: car.name,
)
```

Comment: If you want the effect of partial select like [Flutter: Parent and child checkboxes](https://medium.com/@nishsvn.dev/flutter-parent-and-child-checkboxes-part-2-98ce62156004), you may need to handle the null case of the checkbox of Country,

Comment: You are just a great programmer :) I didn’t even hope that I could find solutions to this problem with my approach. I am pleased to award you a bounty

Answer (score 0):

Try this I Hope it works for you.

```
          @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  for (Country country in countries)
                    ExpansionTile(
                        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        title: CheckboxListTile(
                          value:
                          getCountryValue(country),
    
                          onChanged: (check) =>
                              onCountrySelected(check!, country),
                          title: Text(country.name!),
                        ),
                        initiallyExpanded: () {
                          return false;
                        }(),
                        children: [
                          for (Car car in country.cars!)
                            CheckboxListTile(
                              value: selectedCar.contains(car),
                              onChanged: (check) =>
                                  _handleCheckFilter(check!, 'cars', car),
                              title: Text(car.name!),
                            )
                        ])
                ]),
          ),
        );
      }
    
    
    
      List<Car> selectedCar = [];
    
      void _handleCheckFilter(bool checked, String key, Car car) {
        if (checked) {
        selectedCar.add(car);
        } else {
          selectedCar.remove(car);
        }
        setState(() {
        });
      }
    
      onCountrySelected(bool checked, Country country) {
        if (checked) {
          country.cars!.forEach((element) {
            if (!selectedCar.contains(element)) {
              selectedCar.add(element);
            }
          });
        } else {
          country.cars!.forEach((element) {
            selectedCar.remove(element);
          });
        }
        setState(() {
    
        });
      }
    
      bool getCountryValue(Country country) {
        bool selected = country.cars!.where((element) => selectedCar.contains(element)).length == country.cars!.length;
        return selected;
      }
    
      List<Country> countries = [
        Country(
          name: 'Germany',
          cars: [
            Car(name: 'Audi'),
            Car(name: 'BMW'),
            Car(name: 'Volkswagen'),
          ],
        ),
        Country(
          name: 'Sweden',
          cars: [
            Car(name: 'Koenigsegg'),
            Car(name: 'Polestar'),
            Car(name: 'Volvo'),
          ],
        ),
        Country(
          name: 'Russian',
          cars: [
            Car(name: 'GAZ'),
            Car(name: 'Lada'),
            Car(name: 'ZAZ'),
          ],
        ),
      ];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it works, but only partially. The fact is that my code could store the state of checkboxes, that is, if there were checkboxes on the checkboxes, then they continued to be there after the filter window was closed. Is it possible to leave this functionality with your code?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Can you help me with this, because I have already spent a lot of time and can not get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will keep the states

```
class _FilterDialogUserState extends State<FilterDialogUser> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
   @override
   bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
   
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     super.build(context);
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand how to save the state in my code, I need to implement the functionality that is described in the condition